# Multi Room Chat Application using SilverLight 4.0 and PollingDuplex

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I'm looking for a sample or guidelines to build a multi room chat application using SL 4.0 and PollingDuplex.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Dan Wahlin did a great article on this topic:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/19/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-a-wcf-duplex-service-part-ii.aspx

On SilverlightTV you can watch an episode about Silverlight 4.0 and Duplex communication:

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/duplex-communication-with-wcf-in-silverlight-4-silverlight-tv-34/

There was a session on NDC 2010 about communication with Silverlight 4, but I can't find the link to the video, sorry.

Hope that helps you a little bit.

Greets

Comment: I really need a "Multi Room" implementation guidelines, by Multi Room i mean multiple PollingDuplex connexions by the same client