# How to implement chat functionality in windows phone 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

please tell me idea for how to implement chat functionality in WP7?in my app i need to communicate from one user to another user.how to achieve this?
what is the better way to implement chat?
Please tell me idea for this...

thanks in advance

Comment: Please let me know the solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for Silverlight 3-4 chat implementation. One of the results might help you: [Multi Room Chat Application using SilverLight 4.0 and PollingDuplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429977/multi-room-chat-application-using-silverlight-4-0-and-pollingduplex)

For displaying chat, you can use [Conversation View from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx#conversationview)

Comment: Thanks @Alex..Is there any frameworks  to implement chat in WP7?like XMPP etc.please clarify any other alternatives for easy implementation of chat..

Comment: Take a look at Buddy.com platform. Or QuickBlox

Answer (score 0):

Twilio is a librarie that supports chat/sms or even VoIP and they have a .NET Api. Don't know if it will work on WP: https://www.twilio.com

Comment: is there any XMPP sdk to implement chat in wp7?